# Precedence of || and && operators in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
   m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
   printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, k, m);
}
```

Output :

> -2 2 0 1

Why should the expression `m=++i||++j&&++k`; not parsed as `m=++i||(++j&&++k)` as the precedence of && is higher than || ??

Comment: Quite a coincidence that your program uses the exact same variables and values as the duplicate question. :)

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't; the duplicate does not use `||` at all

Comment: Ahh, they're identical except that the first `&&` has been changed to `||`.

Comment: Operator precedence != order of evaluation && left-to-right associativity != left-to-right evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

`||` and `&&` are short circuit operators. If the final result is evaluated from the left operand, right operand is **not** evaluated.

```
++i ||  /* Evaluate ++i which is -2, so the result of expression is 1 */
  ++j && ++k;  /* No need to evaluated this */
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed and is specific to compiler implementation.

Comment: No, this is guaranteed by the specs

Comment: @Atmocreations logical operators in C-like languages are always shortcircuited by standard

Comment: @Atmocreations 6.5.13/4 `"...the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
operand is not evaluated."`  The standard can't really be more clear than that.